# Enabling the "Check / Money Order" Payment option in Admin does not make it appear on the front-end

Tags: payment-methods

I selected **Enabled YES** on the "*Check / Money Order*" Payment option in SYSTEM - CONFIGURATION - SALES - PAYMENT METHODS but **the option does NOT show up on the front end** (only the other option which is Saved CC shows up)

It takes a long time to save after I make that change but eventually saves that choice (even when I go out and come back in - it shows ENABLED - YES). What do you think the problem might be?

I restarted the Apache Web Server AND SQL Server (MySQL), deleted ALL CACHE AND re-indexed but it did not seem to help.

There is currently no load on the server at all: Load Averages: 0.16 0.30 0.35

Recently - we had an episode with hosting - categories would not load properly on the back-end. They said this: `It looks like mod_security is blocking this.`

And then:

> We have whitelisted mod security rules that were blocking your site.
> (that fixed the problem with the categories not loading back then)

Do you think this is likely the problem now?

**Magento version 1.9.1.0 with the following modifications:**

> free Access theme installed
> (http://accessshopthemes.com/magento-themes/accessshop-lite/ )
>
> calendar installed (BSS GROUP EXTENSION)
>
> ASchroder.com SMTP Pro Email Extension

Comment: Is it a heavily customized site? That's the only reason why that could be happening.

Comment: Make sure it is enabled in the store as well, not just default. You can check that in _Current Configuration Scope:_ at the top left of the config page.

Comment: Erfan - I would not say it is 'heavily customized' --) Magento version 1.9.1.0 with the following modifications:

free Access theme installed ( http://accessshopthemes.com/magento-themes/accessshop-lite/ )
calendar installed (BSS GROUP EXTENSION)
ASchroder.com SMTP Pro Email Extension                                                                    The problem started when we did not even have the SMTP Pro Email Extension installed - just the theme and calendar

Comment: Kiatng: I checked and it is enabled in all the stores/storefronts...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Try this solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155944/disable-payment-method-on-frontend-only