# Disable payment method on frontend only

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.0.7

How to disable payment method

> Check / Money Order

only on frontend, but left available for admin on backend ?

I can't find solution for M2

Comment: override payment method  by custom module.

Comment: `<can_use_checkout>0</can_use_checkout>` in your payment `config.xml` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to implement [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121020/34234) simple solution, but it hides method both in backend and frontend, so I modify plugin this way (added check for current area):

```
class Available
{
    private $app_state;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $app_state){
        $this->app_state = $app_state;
    }

    public function afterIsAvailable(\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod $subject, $result)
    {
        $area_code  = $this->app_state->getAreaCode();
        if($area_code != \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE){
            if($subject->getCode() == 'checkmo') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best idea to use **event/observer** concept.Fire an observer on event: `payment_method_is_active`

Create `events.xml` at **`app\code\[Vendorname]\[Modulename]\etc\`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="disable_pg" instance="[Vendorname]\[Modulename]\Observer\ObserverforDisabledFrontendPg" />
    </event>
</config>
```

then at observer class **ObserverforDisabledFrontendPg.php** rewrite below code:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendorname]\[Modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverforDisabledFrontendPg implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_appState;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
    ) {
        $this->_appState = $appState;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
      $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
      $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

      if(null !== $quote){
          /* 
          *  During Checkout magento call payment methods from both
          *   area frontend and Web_api are
          */

          if($method_instance->getCode() =='checkmo' && 
            in_array($this->_appState->getAreaCode(), $this->getDisableAreas()))
            {
               $result->setData('is_available',false);
               //$items= $quote->getAllVisibleItems();    
          }
      }

    }      

    protected function getDisableAreas(){

        return array( \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_WEBAPI_REST);
    }


}
```

Comment: A small change `$result->setData('is_available',false);`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to disable the payment method at the front end is the **Plugin**.

Create di.xml file in you custom module

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="restrictByCustomer1"                type="{Namespace}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Payment\Method\Checkmo\Available"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

create plugin file in your module
app/code/{Namespace}/{Modulename}/Plugin/Payment/Method/Checkmo/Available.php
add below code into the plugin file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace {Namespace}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Payment\Method\Checkmo;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Checkmo;

class Available
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $backendSession;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     * @param BackendSession $backendSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        BackendSession $backendSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Cashondelivery $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function afterIsAvailable(Checkmo $subject, $result)
    {
        // Do not remove payment method for admin
        if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        // Hide payment method from front-end only
        /*$isLogged = $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
        if (!$isLogged) {
            return false;
        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good option. What if customer is not login and does checkout ??