# How to show all payment methods in admin - Sales / Order / Create New Order not in front end

Tags: magento2, magento-admin

Is it possible to show disabled payment methods only in admin while creating order from Admin / Sales / Orders and not in front end.

Comment: Yes, but you will either need an extension (eg https://www.magepal.com/payment-restrictions-for-magento-2.html) or create your own see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155944/disable-payment-method-on-frontend-only

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin to control which method you will show in the frontend, creating a plugin for:

```
Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList
```

Then you check the method by code and disabled which you want:

```
public function afterGetAvailableMethods(\Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList $subject, $result)
{
    foreach ($result as $key=>$_result) {
        if ($_result->getCode() == "cashondelivery") {
            unset($result[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In this way, you can show the payment method in the admin area only and disable it in the frontend area.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Create a global event for `payment_method_is_active`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="mp_payment_restrictions" instance="MagePal\PaymentRestrictions\Observer\PaymentMethodActiveObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In MagePal/PaymentRestrictions/Observer/PaymentMethodActiveObserver.php

```
class PaymentMethodActiveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        ..
    ) {
        ...
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {  

        $methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        $paymentCode = $methodInstance->getCode();  

        //todo: check if processing from backend or frontend 
        if ($result->getIsAvailable() && $paymentCode !== 'xyz') {
           $result->setIsAvailable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is not working. Still am getting only "Purchased Order" method nothing else.

Comment: Can you add some code to your original post?